# Problems in creating JSF project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jsf-2

I want to create a JSF project. I took help of this tutorial
http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaServerFaces/article.html

I followed exactly same step to create project. But after creating project when I run this in my server with url "http://localhost:8080/url/faces/NewFile.jsp" it is showing me error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application was not properly
>   initialized at startup, could not find Factory:
>   javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory

Also I want to mention that I have added jsf-api-1.2 and jsf-impl-1.2.

I am using

- Browser- firefox
- Server- Apache tomcat 6.0
- JSF- 2.0
- Eclipse- Indigo 3.7.0

Comment: what does your web.xml look like?

Comment: Eclipse has build web.xml file. I have not changed any thing except welcome file tag.  <welcome-file>NewFile.jsp</welcome-file>

Comment: You're using a JSF 1.2, not JSF 2.0 libraries. There must be a problem in your web.xml or you've put the JSF jars in the wrong folder (outise WEB-INF/lib). Please post your web.xml file and your folder structure in order to help. Also, it would be better to check the JSF 2 guide in [our wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info)

Comment: Sorry I am not able to put my web.xml in comment box since its allowing me only 600 characters. Well I tried with JSF1.2 with same jar files(as u said that these are for JSF1.2). But I am facing same problem. I think might be I have placed jar files in wrong location.. Can you suggest me required jar files and their right location to put them. If you can described the steps that would be very good for me.

Comment: jars should be in /web/WEB_INF/lib folder

Comment: Problem solved. Actually I was missing jstl jar file. So I placed it in /WebContent/WEB_INF/lib folder and after that choosing build patch I added it to the library. That solved my problem... Thank you all for help.. :)